# Converting images from cvimg to tensor properly

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

Is there a proper way to convert a cvimg to tensor properly without causing any color distortions? I have done a comparison by storing 2 images. One was decoded using tensorflow and the other was done using openCV

[image: This is supposed to be the original image]
Image generated using tensorflow jpeg encoder

```py
  file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
  if file_name.endswith(".png"):
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_png(
        file_reader, channels=3, name="png_reader")
  elif file_name.endswith(".gif"):
    image_reader = tf.squeeze(
        tf.image.decode_gif(file_reader, name="gif_reader"))
  elif file_name.endswith(".bmp"):
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_bmp(file_reader, name="bmp_reader")
  else:
    image_reader = tf.image.decode_jpeg(
        file_reader, channels=3, name="jpeg_reader")
```

[image]
Image generated using cv to tensor convert.

```py
image_reader = tf.convert_to_tensor(cvimg)
```

Am i missing some steps here during the cv conversion? Thanks!

Comment: Your code look incomplete. How do you get cvimg?

Comment: ah the cvimg was passed in from another module. It is a BGR image apparently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV loads images in the BGR format while Tensorflow uses the RGB format (as you can see the blue and red channels of your image are swapped).

Thus, if you want to read an image loaded using OpenCV (i suppose `cvimg`) you just have to swap the color channels from BGR to RGB:

```py
image_reader = tf.convert_to_tensor(cvimg)
b, g, r = tf.unstack (image_reader, axis=-1)
image_reader = tf.stack([r, g, b], axis=-1)
```

Comment: Oh thanks! You're a lifesaver, I thought the image info clearly stated RGB and OpenCV wouldn't convert it to BGR on load. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
 image_reader=tf.reverse(cvimg,axis=[-1])
```

`tf.reverse` will reverse the order that you specified dimension.because the `cvimg(opencv image,[height,width,channel])` is BGR  format,
so `tf.reverse(cvimg,axis=[-1])` will reverse BGR(the last dimension) to RGB,
you don't have to use `tf.convert_to_tensor(cvimg)`, because tensorfow will automatically convert from numpy array to tensor.

Comment: While this might be a valuable input, please add an explanation

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Because my English is poor,  I worry my expression  is not clear.